# Выравнивание слова в TextView (метод Spritz)

Tags: android

Подскажите как можно выровнять текст в TextView относительно красной черточки (метод выравнивание слова методом Spritz).
Вот метод выравнивания
[image: метод RSVP и метод Spritz]

Вот красные метки с TextView
[image: красные метки]

Comment: Можно попробовать реализовать свой `Span` по аналогии с `AlignmentSpan`, но возможно сделать свой кастомный контрол для такой задачи будет проще.

Comment: есть такакя библиотека, возможно вам подойдет
https://github.com/andrewgiang/SpritzerTextView